# chrome browser dragging tabs jumps from one workspace to another on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, browser, xorg, chromium

I decided to change from firefox to a chrome based browser on my ubuntu 20.04 and I got the following problem:

I open two full screen windows on two different workspace. The problem I get is that on one of the window when I try to drag a tab to reorder my tabs, it jumps to the other window. It happens every time. It is like there were a "main" window in which all the tabs were sent when moving it.

It happens with every chrome-based browser (e.g chromium, brave etc...) and it is very annoying as firefox really upsets me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: same here, ubuntu 20, with Brave, it started happening a month or two ago and it's very annoying indeed

Comment: I can't even drag and drop in Asana without it changing workspaces. Completely unusable now :( On Ubuntu 21.10 with Chrome 96.

Comment: Got it just after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. I have a single workspace, so what happens instead is that the tab simply pops up as a separate window, making it impossible to reorder tabs or move them inside some tab group. Workaround is to Ctrl+Shift+Page Up/Down to move right/left, and right-click > Add tab to group / Move tab to another window as needed. Worth a bug report, although I'm not sure where to put it: Chrome or Ubuntu. Probably notify both and let them sort out.

Comment: By the way the issue may be related with Chromium being distributed as snap and missing some permissions. I currently encounter other issues like not being able to open nautilus when clicking on a downloaded item.

Comment: Update: may not be related to snap after all, as using a trick from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home to run Chrome as non-snap fixes the open nautilus issue, but not the tab drag issue.

Comment: Can confirm on Linux Mint 20.2

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the chrome tab bar and remove checked from the "Use system title bar and borders" option. That fixed it for me.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it didn't fix it for me. It just hid the title when the window is not fullscreen.

Answer (score 3):

Please update to Google Chrome 97. I upgraded from Google Chrome 96 where this behaviour was occurring and it is fixed.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/rv84mp/browser_tabs_moving_jumps_workspaces/

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me.

Comment: Can confirm this fixed it for me on 21.10... I was already on 97.0.x and that was the version that introduced this problem for me. And upgrading to 97.0.4692.99 resolved the issue.

Comment: the update from 97 to... the new 97 worked for me. tabs now drag-and-drop into different chrome windows as expected